# RunTimeException: Binary XML file line : Error inflating class with SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am starting my layout in the MainActivity and I every time the same error. My MainActivity, My SurfaceView is an innerclass in the MainActivity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.backlayout);
```

backlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity" >



    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="TEST-IT"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <view class = "com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity$DrawingPanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DrawingPanel:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private DrawingThread _thread;
    private Path path;

    public DrawingPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
    }

    public DrawingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet atr) {
        super(context, atr);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _thread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
    }

    ... some crazy stuff

}
```

Error Log:

```
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.drawingapp/com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity$DrawingPanel
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity$DrawingPanel
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:589)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:269)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1885)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     ... 11 more
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
05-12 12:41:19.702: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     ... 22 more
```

I tried many different ways with changing this part of the XML file, e.g.:

```
 <view class = "com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity$DrawingPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

to

```
 <com.example.drawingapp.MainActivity.DrawingPanel
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: please create stand alone class for DrawingPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DrawingPanel` is an inner class in `MainActivity` so it must be declared as `static` so it can be constructed without the outer class object.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
 <com.example.drawingapp.DrawingPanel
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: sorry, didnt mentioned that DrawingPanel is an innerclass